# How to remove all except the first 3 and last of a specific character with sed

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed

I've looked all over the place but can't find an answer. I've used sed before so I'm familiar with the syntax - however this one has me stumped.

I want to remove all except the first 3 instances and the last instance of a specific character. Here is a specific example:

input.csv:

```
"first", "some text "quote" blaw blaw", 1
"second", "some more text "another quote" blaw blaw", 3
```

I want to remove all the quotes (") except for the first three and the last one so that it looks like this:

output.csv:

```
"first", "some text quote blaw blaw", 1
"second", "some more text another quote blaw blaw", 3
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? We don't want to waste your time suggesting things you have already tried.

Comment: Well... I knew that this wouldn't work before I tried it - no surprise it didn't work:

sed -r -e 's/(\"{3})\"/\1/' -e 's/\"(\"{1})/\1/'  input.csv > output.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -r ':a; s/([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*")([^"]*)"([^"]*")/\1\2\3/; ta' input.csv
"first", "some text quote blaw blaw", 1
"second", "some more text another quote blaw blaw", 3
```

#### How it works

The code works by looking for the  first five quotes.  It removes the fourth.  This process is repeated by looping until there are only four quotes left.

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*")([^"]*)"([^"]*")/\1\2\3/`

  This looks for the the first three quotes and all text that that precedes them as group 1.  It looks for the next set of non-quote characters as group 2. It looks for the following double quote.  It then looks for non-quote characters followed by a fifth quote as group 3.  It replaces that with the three groups, omitting the fourth quote.

  Let's break this down more explicitly:

  - `([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*")`

    This looks for the the first three quotes and all text that that precedes them.  This is saved as group 1.
  - `([^"]*)`

    This looks for the next set of non-quote characters.  They are saved as group 2.
  - `"`

    This matches the fourth quote on the line.
  - `([^"]*")`

    This matches the next group of non-quote characters followed by the fifth quote on the line.  It is saved as group 3.

  The replacement text is `\1\2\3` which has the effect of removing the fourth quote of the five quotes found.
- `ta`

  If a substitution was made, this loops back to label `a`.  If not, then we are done with this line.

#### BSD or Mac OSX

Try:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*")([^"]*)"([^"]*")/\1\2\3/' -e 'ta' input.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation - that really helps me understand the syntax. However, for some reason, when I run this, none of the quotes are removed... Also, if it isn't too much trouble, could you explain the replacement text line? It's unlike what I've seen previously. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @justanotherbrain What OS are you on?  (The quoting style that I have used is appropriate for unix-style shell.)  I updated the answer with a longer explanation for the three groups that are used in the replacement text.

Comment: Thanks, this should work fine - I'm on debian. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With awk, use the double quote as a field separator:

```
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" '{
   text=""
   for (i=4; i<NF; i++) text = text $i
   print $1,$2, $3, text, $NF
}' <<END
"first", "some text "quote" blaw blaw", 1
"second", "some more text "another quote" blaw blaw", 3
END
```

```
"first", "some text quote blaw blaw", 1
"second", "some more text another quote blaw blaw", 3
```

On the other hand, if you want to repair that broken CSV, then interior quotes should be doubled:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=, '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^".*"$/) {
            newtext = substr($i, 2, length($i)-2)
            gsub(/"/, "\"\"", newtext)
            $i = "\"" newtext "\""
        }
    }
    print
}' data
```

```
"first","some text ""quote"" blaw blaw",1
"second","some more text ""another quote"" blaw blaw",3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Fixing the csv might work, though I'm going to strip special characters later anyways - however, when I passed the csv into the second script you provided, interior quotes were still single... probably an error on my end. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)"/\1\n/;/s/"//4g;s/\n/"/' file
```

This replaces the last `"` with a unique character (`\n`) then removes all `"`'s from the fourth onwards and finally replaces the unique character with a `"`.